# Is there a way to search a SQL Query with Month Numbers, and not Month Name?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to use the actual numerical value for the month on a sql query to pull results.  Is there any way to do this without having a function to change the numbers to actual month names, then back to month numbers?  The following code works for Names, what works for numbers?

> datename(month,(convert(datetime,DTSTAMP)))=
>   'October'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

month,(convert(datetime,DTSTAMP)) should do it, but why on earth are you not storing the data correctly as a datetime to begin with? All that additional conversion  stuff to use the dates adds unnecessary load to your server and slows down your application.

Answer (score 0):

[Datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(SQL.80).aspx) is an alternative to the month command and it is more flexable as you can extract other parts of the date.

```
DATEPART(mm, convert(datetime,DTSTAMP))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets Month Number of Date

CONVERT(VARCHAR(2) ,DTSTAMP ,110)

Answer (score 0):

here, you can search with diff options like:

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

as per your requirement.